# All possible combinations of seven numbers that sum up to a specific value under constraints.

Tags: summation, integer-partitions

I know this (or similar questions) may have already been asked a ton of times, but I couldn't really find a good answer for my specific case, so here again. I would like to implement the following formula:

$G(0,1,\ldots,5) =0$

$G(N) = G(N-1) + \underbrace{\sum\limits_{a}\sum\limits_{b}\sum\limits_{c}\sum\limits_{d}\sum\limits_{e}\sum\limits_{f}\sum\limits_{g}}_{a+b+c+d+e+f+g=N-6} F(a)F(b)F(c)F(d)F(e)F(f)F(g)$

with $N\in \lbrace 6,7,\ldots,180\cdot 7 -1\rbrace$ and $a,b,\ldots,g\in\lbrace 0,1,\ldots,179\rbrace$,

in Python, whereby F is a float number between 0 and 1.

The problem is that everytime I get it done it doesn't really work due to the high number of loops and so on. My math related question now is: Is there a way to simplify this formula? (so that it somehow doesn't contain so many sums in one go, etc.)

Again if there is a solution somewhere I would also be glad to just be redirected to it. :D Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$T(n, k) = \sum\limits_{x_1 + \ldots + x_k = n} \prod\limits_{i=1}^k F(x_i)$$

Then your expression can be rewritten as $G(N) = G(N - 1) + T(N - 6, 7)$.

And $T(n, k)$ can be computed in $O(n^2k)$ operations using standard dynamic programming or recursion with memorization, as we have $$T(n, k + 1) = \sum\limits_{x_{k + 1} = 0}^{179} F(x_{k + 1}) \cdot T(n - x_{k + 1}, k)$$

Comment: I do have one last question: Does this actually take into consideration that (let the tuple be (x1, x2, ..., x6)) there is e.g. (1,0,0,0,0,0) and (0,1,0,0,0,0) etc. ?, meaning does it take all permuations into account this recusive T(n,k+1) formula here? :D

Comment: Yes, it does. Summation in definition of $T$ is over all possible tuples, and recursive formula is just reordering (grouping terms with the same value of the last element of tuple).